# In Javascript console when console.log(a variable) if reloading the page change the info it shows

Tags: javascript, variables, console

I have this code

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Press 1</button>
    <button>Press 2</button>
    <button>Press 3</button>
</div>
<script>
    const buttonContainer = document.querySelector('.buttons');
    console.log('buttonContainer', buttonContainer);
  
    buttonContainer.addEventListener('click', event => {
        console.log(event.target);
    })
</script>
```

when open the console for the first time, it shows this:
[image: (arrow)div.buttons]

where I can see the properties and methods of the variable.

When reloading the page, it changes to this:
[image: <div class: "buttons">...]

Any one could explain to me why it happens? and how i can toggle between 2 of those options, I see very helpfull to see the list of the properties and methos of my variable when needed.

Thanks :)

Comment: Both are exactly the same, the first one is just expanded

Comment: No. when expanding the first one it shows all the properties and methods of the variable

Comment: yes!! thanks soo much :)

Answer (score -1):

its because that script is downloaded in parallel to parsing the page, and the rendering tree might not be parsed yet. to fix this, add `defer` prop to your script. That should make it execute after the parsing.

Comment: ok, but do you know how to change between them? because a see usefull to have all the list of the proterties and methods

Comment: @MrCeRaYA Do you have something to back up those claims?

Comment: @Ivar https://v8.dev/blog/code-caching-for-devs

Comment: @MrCeRaYA Does that page also mention that this affects how `console.log()`'s are shown (as we are discussing here)? I skimmed through the text but didn't see it. It seems a bit farfetched.

Comment: @Ivar upon further investigation, ive found the proper solution for the problem, a one that can satisfy both of you :)

Comment: @zero0 a solution is represented in the answer

Comment: @MrCeRaYA If it ins't parsed yet, `document.querySelector` wouldn't have found the element and when that's the case, it will return `null`. (And it is logging "div.buttons", not `null`.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238764/discussion-between-mrceraya-and-ivar).

Comment: @Ivar info posted in chat